# How to find last occurrence of pattern and print 20 lines before the occurence of a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

Need to find the last occurrence of pattern and print 20 lines BEFORE the pattern.
So, I tried a known sed command found on this website but it prints all lines after the last occurrence until the end.

```
sed -n '/====/h;//!H;$!d;x;//p' sample.txt
```

Can someone please help me to get or print 20 lines before the pattern `====`.

So here's my input:
let's assume we've 20K lines and the last pattern is at the end of the file

- first line before pattern
- second line before pattern
- third line before pattern
- .... goes upto 20 lines before pattern
- actual pattern
- do not need first line after pattern
- do not need second line after pattern
- in short do not need any lines after pattern

> > with the above sed. I get the actual pattern and the first line, second line,and the rest of the lines after the pattern until the end of file.
> > In the meanwhile, wrote a 2 liner bash script as follows:

- holdline=$(awk '/=====/ {line=NR} END {print line}' inputfile
- befholdline=$(expr $holdline - 20)
- awk -v befholdline=$befholdline -v holdline=$holdline 'NR >= befholdline && NR <= holdline'

> which works for me but I think this code is unnecessary and can be done smarter. I think certain commands like tac or grep -A or -B doesn't work on certain unix flavor.

Comment: please update the question with some sample data, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output; to minimize the sample set show what you'd expect for a match plus, say, the 3 lines before the match

Comment: Just print the 20 lines before every occurrence of the patttern and take the last 20 `grep -B20 === FILE | tail -20`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I suggest to replace `-20` with `-21` or `-n 21` to get last row and 20 before last row.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, thank you - I must learning adding up and taking away soon 

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Since sample wasn't provided, I created one:

```bash
$ cat ip.txt
apple
===
1
2
3
===
banana
fig
mango
cherry
===
42
3.14

$ tac ip.txt | grep -m1 -A3 '===' | tac
fig
mango
cherry
===
```

`tac` is handy for such cases. After reversing input line wise, you can use standard solutions to get the required text and then reverse again. Change the value passed to the `-A` option and the search string as needed.

OP's edit is still not clear. Just in case the requirement is matching a line and printing few context lines before:

```bash
$ grep -B1 'fig' ip.txt
banana
fig
```

In the above example, `fig` is the search term and `-B` option helps to get lines before the matching one.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task, let `file.txt` content be

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
=====
26
27
28
29
30
```

then

```
awk '{arr[NR]=$0;delete arr[NR-21]}/=====/{for(i=-20;i<=0;i+=1){print arr[NR+i]}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
=====
```

Explanation: I save whole line into array `arr` under key being number of row, then delete line which is 21 lines before, as it is no longer necessary, observe that it might not exist yet, however this is not problem as for [`delete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Delete.html)

> It is not an error to delete an element that does not exist.

When pattern is found I `print` 20 last lines stored in array `arr` using `for` loop, going from current line minus 20 to current line minus zero. Note that if pattern is found before 20th line, my code assumes that it should assume empty lines before actual file. You might elect to drop `delete` part if you are okay with ramming all lines inside memory.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: the code is perfect but the only problem here is it is printing all the 20 lines before the 12,000 pattern in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
{
    a[NR] = $0
    delete a[NR - 21]                           # use array "a" as a fifo
}
/=====/ {                                       # if the pattern matches
    start = NR >= 21 ? 1 : 22 - NR              # suppress empty lines if the line count < 20
    for (i = start; i <= 21; i++)               # copy array "a" to array "b" to keep the final result
        b[i] = a[NR - 21 + i]
}
END {
    if (start)                                  # print output only if match occurred
        for (i = start; i <= 21; i++)
            print b[i]
}
' file.txt
```

If you prefer a one-liner (less readable):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0;delete a[NR-21]}/=====/{start=NR>=21?1:22-NR;for(i=start;i<=21;i++)b[i]=a[NR-21+i]}END{if(start)for(i=start;i<=21;i++)print b[i]}' file.txt
```